# update a object second value as a object with JSON_SET in mysql apostrof problem

Tags: mysql, node.js

I hava a longtext type column in mysql and it is default value is like that :

```
{"aaaaa": [], "bbbbb": []}
```

when I want to update that column with :

```
const IamCreator = 1;
const myValue= [1,22,66,77]; //object

const query = `UPDATE 8users SET content = JSON_SET(content, '$.aaaaa', '?') WHERE id = ?`;
            connection.query(query,[myValue,IamCreator],function (err, result, fields) {
                console.log(err)
            })
```

it give syntex problemand update value like that ;

{"aaaaa": "[1,22,66,77]", "bbbbb": []}

how can I solve that appostrof prolem?

I tried :

```
content = JSON_SET(content, '$.aaaaa', ?) 
content = JSON_SET(content,'$.aaaaa', [?]) 
const query = `UPDATE table SET json_column = JSON_SET(json_column, '$.mykanban', ?) WHERE id = ?`; connection.query(query, [JSON.stringify(myValue), IamCreator]);
```

ı took syntex error all the time